# Where is addEventListener specced for DOM 2 HTML?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, w3c

I have an app ([ObjJob](http://objjob.phrogz.net)) that shows the interplay of JavaScript bindings for various web-related standards. I just noticed today that HTML elements like [`HTMLButtonElement`](http://objjob.phrogz.net/html/object/274) don't include [`addEventListener()`](http://objjob.phrogz.net/events/method/604) as an available method. I assumed that I had made a mistake during data import, but I can't find it.

- The [DOM 2 HTML IDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/idl-definitions.html) only shows `HTMLElement` [inheriting from `dom::Element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-58190037).
- The [DOM 2 Core IDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/idl-definitions.html) does not include the text "event" anywhere.
- The [DOM 2 Events IDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/idl-definitions.html) defines the [`EventTarget` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget) but never binds it to `dom::Element`.

The SVG 1.1 specs properly [apply `EventTarget` to `SVGElementInstance`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#InterfaceSVGElementInstance), but I can't find any similar binding for HTML or DOM.

Am I crazy, or is there no official spec that associates events with DOM elements? If there is a normative reference, where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Section 1.3.1 of the DOM2 Events page](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Registration-interfaces) states that *all* DOM `Nodes` should implement the Event Target Interface, which includes `addEventListener` as a method.

So, I think you've run into a bug in the browser.

Comment: Looks like you've found it. Thanks! Frustrating (and odd) that this is not in the IDL, but I'll just manually set `dom::Node` to include `EventTarget`.